# Los números de paginación han desaparecido

Tags: bug

Hace solo unos momentos, he visto como los números han desaparecido en la paginación.
Consulté en el chat rápidamente, y luego vine a realizar la publicación acá.

En esta imagen, me di cuenta que el numero "5" no se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con una rápida selección me doy cuenta que el número si está, pero no se vee, por lo que el css debe tener algo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adentrándome más en el css, logro obtener esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mmm usas el plugin de comentarios? inténtalo con un navegador sin pluggins

Comment: No uso plugins de comentarios.

Comment: Esto debe ir a meta general...

Comment: a lo que me refiero es que muy probablemente hay algo mal en tu PC... por que a mi me carga correctamente todo...

Comment: Solo tengo Gyazo (capturador de imagenes) que no  afecta la página y AdBlock, el cual no está activado en la página.

Comment: que raro y si borra el chache de la pagina y todas las cookies y te logeas nuevamente???

Comment: deberias agregar los pasos para reproducir el bug

Comment: Caché borrada, primera sugerencia del chat, no hay pasos para reproducir el bug, es en la apertura de la página. Podría añadir que es Chrome a lo máximo.